# XAML & c# virtual keyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, textbox, keyboard

I have a problem with virtual keyboards. I have a simple "textbox" in XAML like:

`<TextBox Header="VirtualK" InputScope="Default"/>`

What should I do to make the keyboard appear? To use it? I doing a **Universal Windows** app with Visual Studio and I need to "draw" with XAML and complete in C#.

I have tried some solution before but nothing work for me.

Thank you...

Comment: Is this Xamarin Forms? If so what device is this running on?  Also if it is Xamarin Forms TextBox control is Called Entry Not TextBox.  In Xamarin Forms the OnScreen Keboard should activate when you click or tap into a Entry box.

Comment: It is Universal Windows so I don't have the "Entry" function

Comment: Are you debugging this on Windows running in Desktop Mode?  I think the only time Keyboard is automatically triggered is when OS is in Tablet mode,  you can set that like so, https://www.windowscentral.com/what-tablet-mode-windows-10

Comment: I'm debugging in a tablet with raspberry. I have installed Windows 10 IoT core

Comment: Looks like there is an option in device Settings on IoT Core that needs to be checked for On-screen Keyboard to show when text input controls have focus,https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOhPW.png

Comment: Bearcat9425 it work, thank you!!